# How can I set up a category "overview" page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, taxonomy, templates, template-hierarchy

I know I can use the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to set up custom theme pages for terms inside a category, like these:

```
mysite.com/category/tech/              // category-tech.php
mysite.com/category/blog/              // category-blog.php
mysite.com/category/featured/          // category-featured.php
```

`category.php` does not seem to work for the overview page, but it would work for a page like `mysite.com/category/tech/` if a more specific template file (`category-tech.php`) was not available. I want to create a "category overview" page (`mysite.com/category/`) which would show all the terms of the `category` taxonomy.

Similarly, I would also like to be able to do this with a custom taxonomy, such as `mysite.com/books/` in this case:

```
mysite.com/books/fiction/
mysite.com/books/non-fiction/
mysite.com/books/science/
```

I do want this done dynamically, i.e. I don't want to create a page called 'category' with a permalink `category` and then add the items to that page. I think it would work but that seems like a hack.

Comment: do you want category overview page to just list all the categories or something else?

Comment: You mentioned category.php not working - For what I'm hearing you describe, that _should_ work well. Custom taxonomies, of course, would need to be handled with their own template. Can you describe what's not working about category.php? Let's get that one figured out first.

Comment: @JonathanWold basically if you visit `http://yoursite.com/category/`, and replace yoursite.com with a wordpress site, but don't replace `/category/` with anything else, you will get a 404 page. This is the url I would like to be able to hook into and do something such a list all of the categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default rewrite to a template for a category or taxonomy landing page.  You are correct, that this can be done by creating a custom template and applying it to a page.

Comment: What happens when you visit your wordpress site /category/ ? I'm assuming you will get a not found page.

Comment: You can create a new page and assign a template to it, you are correct that by default there is no rewrite to category.php.

Comment: see question `I do want this done dynamically, i.e. I don't want to create a page called 'category' `

Comment: `by default there is no rewrite`

Comment: looks like anything else is too complicated so even though I mentioned I did not want to create a page called "category" this is probably the best way